# eclipse: categorizing breakpoints in debugger

Tags: eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

In a multimillion line project, sometimes when searching for a bug, you can end up creating several dozen breakpoints.  Often these breakpoints are searching for slightly different things.

Eclipse displays the class, line number, and method in which the breakpoint lies, but that's not always enough for me to keep track of everything.  Sometimes I will know that there are a couple of specific things I want to look at, and I'll have a set of breakpoints digging through each of them.  It would be really useful to be able to create breakpoint categories to help me keep track of where everything I want to look at happens.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this, either in stock eclipse, or with a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

In the breakpoints view, open the view menu and select **Working Sets...**.  This will allow you to create categories.  Once you create a new working set and select the breakpoints to include in it, you can open the view menu again and select **Group By** > **Breakpoint Working Sets**.  This will group your breakpoints into categories.